# Angular 4 - http.post doesn't receive list of objects

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic3

I would like to make a `http.post` request, to receive a list of objects from PHP with `.subscribe`.

When I do that, I receive something like a string which contains my objects.
But in a `*ngFor` loop, the console says me the list is an `undefined` variable.
Here is my code :

**list-master.ts**

```
  /////
  objet01 = {ville: 'Bordeaux', prix: '69€'};
  objet02 = {ville: 'Lille', prix: '45€'};
  objs = [this.objet01, this.objet02];
  /////

  tempproj;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {

    this.http = http;

    this.getprojets();

  }

  getprojets() {
    var link = 'http://*****/getprojets.php';
    var myData = JSON.stringify({value: 'true'});

    this.http.post(link, myData)
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.tempproj = data["_body"]; 
    console.log('OKOK ' + this.tempproj + ' OKOK');
    }, error => {
    console.log("Oooops!");
    });

  }
```

Here is **getprojets.php**:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $value = $request->value;

        if ($value === 'true' ) {
            $bdd = new PDO('***', '***', '***', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

            $query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM projetsapparts") or die('Login invalide');
            $query->execute();
            $liste = array();
            class projet1 {};


 while ($projet = $query->fetch()) {
            $projet1 = new projet1;
            $projet1->ville = $projet['ville'];
            $projet1->photo = $projet['photo'];
            $liste[] = $projet1;
        }
        echo json_encode($liste);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Erreur postdata';
}
```

And then, the **list-master.html**:

```
  <ion-slides class="marketslide" autoplay="3000" loop="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let appart of tempproj">
      <ion-card (tap)="showplvdetails()">
        <img src="{{appart.photo}}">
        <div class="card-title">{{appart.ville}}</div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

In the console, the var tempproj contains 3 entries, it looks like a list of objects :
[{"ville":"Reims","photo":"http:******.jpg"},{"ville":"Paris","photo":"http:******.jpg"},{"ville":"Amsterdam","photo":"http:******.jpg"}]

But, I have this error:

```
Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined
```

When in the .html file, I replace the var `tempproj` by the var `objs` (which is set in .ts file instead of coming from PHP) in the `*ngFor`, all is working fine.

Why does the list of objects from PHP be undefined?
On the `*ngFor="let appart of tempproj"` line, does the 'appart' can be an object?
Please help me, I only find solutions for JavaScript and Angular 2. I'm on it for 5 days.

Comment: define your 'temproj'. as array const tempproj: Array<any> = [];

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
By writing this before the constructor :
tempproj: Array<any> = [];

I have a new error, this one :
ListMasterPage.html:23 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"ville":"Reims","photo":"http:*****.jpg"},{"ville":"Paris","photo":"http:*****.jpg"},{"ville":"Amsterdam","photo":"http:*****.jpg"}]'. 
Only arrays and iterables are allowed

It seems to be better, but always don't working. I don't understand the error log.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your `tempproj` object is undefined at the time your template renders.

Perhaps you could try initializing it to an empty array,

```
let tempproj: Array<any> = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {

    ....
```

Comment: When I write "let" before the variable name, it is highlighted. It's not when I write it IN the constructor, but after compiling, it doesn't work better.

Comment: Ok. Can you create a git repository and share with us?

Comment: I don't know how git works, is it a cloud for files ? Sync with a folder on my computer ? I tried to sign up, then add a new repository, etc.. When i'm here => http://hpics.li/72a52fd  what I have to do ? How do I add files to it ? GitHub Desktop says I cannot publish an unborn branch... => http://hpics.li/194b44e  what does it mean ? Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: After some searches, I can give you this URL for my repository on git, I guess.... https://github.com/Noxstyleprodz/ionicproject02 Is that you asked me for ?

Comment: After some tries of writing types, I think I found the real problem : when I reload the page of the virtual device many times, I got the good work of my code, but only few times (near 1 or 2 of 10). It seems there's a problem with the loading time between HTML code and TS's, I suppose.. :/ What do you think about it ? If I'm right, how can I fix it ?